# Maximum value of $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $f_n(x)=\frac1{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\sqrt{k(n-k)}\binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$ for $x\in[0,1]$. If we put $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\,\,x\in[0,1]$, then what is the maximum value of $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$?

In my opinion, the sequence  $f_n$ is a sequence of Bernstein polynomials, whence the sequence converges uniformly. The term under square root is the one causing trouble. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given continuous $g \in C[0,1]$,  the $n$th Bernstein polynomial $g_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk x^k(1-x)^{n-k} g\left(\frac kn\right)$. It is known that $g_n \to g$ uniformly on the unit interval.

Now, fitting the given $f_n$ into this construct, $f(\frac kn) = \sqrt{\frac{k(n-k)}{n^2}} = \sqrt{\frac kn\left(1-\frac kn\right)} = h(\frac kn)$ where $h(y) = \sqrt {y(1-y)}$, which is a continuous function.

Hence, $f_n \to h$ uniformly on $[0,1]$, hence pointwise. That is ,$h = f$ above. Now, you can solve the question.

Comment: so the guess was right, and fantastic! By the way how did you get the first equation for bernstein polynomial, that is, where did you find this definition of bernstein polynomial?

Comment: On wikipedia for confirmation, but I have seen the Weierstrass approximation theorem before, and usually the conventional proof is via the use of these polynomials.